# jquery get data from radiobutton and textfield

Tags: jquery, forms, text, input, radio-button

I have a survey with more than 100 questions, where there is radiobuttons or textfields.

I figured out how to get the result from the radiobuttons, but I can't get the result from the textfields, into the same result variable as the radiobuttons, called temp.

I use the following code to get the result from the radiobuttons.

```
if($questions.find("input:radio:checked").length === $questions.length)
{
    var temp ='';

    $(':radio').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
          temp += $(this).val()+ ",";
         }
        });

        var currentSurveyName = getQueryVariable("sn");
        var strResult = temp;

        window.location="survey-result.php?sn=" + currentSurveyName + "&sr=" + strResult;   
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Need to check all radiobuttons");
        }
```

And my form code is generated like this:

```
<div class='aQuestion' id='div1'>
<h3>question 1</h3>
<label for='a108'><input type='radio' id='a108' name='grp108' value='0'><span class='answerOption'>0. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='b108'><input type='radio' id='b108' name='grp108' value='1'><span class='answerOption'>1. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='c108'><input type='radio' id='c108' name='grp108' value='2'><span class='answerOption'>2. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='d108'><input type='radio' id='d108' name='grp108' value='3'><span class='answerOption'>3. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='e108'><input type='radio' id='e108' name='grp108' value='4'><span class='answerOption'>4. Answer</span></label>
</div>

<div class='aQuestion' id='div2'>
<h3>question 2</h3>
<label for='a110'><input type='radio' id='a110' name='grp110' value='0'><span class='answerOption'>0. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='b110'><input type='radio' id='b110' name='grp110' value='1'><span class='answerOption'>1. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='c110'><input type='radio' id='c110' name='grp110' value='2'><span class='answerOption'>2. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='d110'><input type='radio' id='d110' name='grp110' value='3'><span class='answerOption'>3. Answer</span></br></label>
<label for='e110'><input type='radio' id='e110' name='grp110' value='4'><span class='answerOption'>4. Answer</span></label>
</div>

<div class='aQuestion' id='div3'>
<h3>question 3</h3>
<input type='text' class='inputField' id='a113' name='grp113'>cm
</div>

<div class='aQuestion' id='div4'>
<h3>question 4</h3>
<input type='text' class='inputField' id='a114' name='grp114'>kg
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :D Tell me if your need more information / code.

What if I would like to check the textfields like I check the radiobuttons below. How would the code look like then?

```
$('.aQuestion').each(function()
        {
            if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0)
            {
                $(this).addClass( "madeChoice" ); 
            }
            else
            {   
                $(this).children("h3").addClass( "didntMakeChoice" );                
            }   

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have for radio:

```
$(':radio').each(function()
{
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        temp += $(this).val()+ ",";
    }
});
```

and simply change it to

```
$(':text').each(function()
{
    if($(this).val() !== "")
    {
        temp += $(this).val() + ",";
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, that actually worked ! I use the following code to run through them all and see if the radiobuttons are checked. (I updated my question)

Comment: I added an little sidequetion to my first question. If someone has the time to take a look at it? :D